# Why is src different for ui.draggable.attr('src') and ui.draggable[0].src

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery drag n drop to drop a thumbnail image into a div and I notice in the drop handler that if I pull the image src with:

```
src = ui.draggable.attr('src');    // brings back relative path
```

I get a relative path: clientImages/t_clown.jpg.  But if I get the raw thumb node and get the src from there I get the full absolute path:  - http:// . . .mysite/clientImages/t_clown.jpg.

```
 var src= ui.draggable[0].src;  // brings back absolute path
```

Does anyone understand why the different treatment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `attr` uses `getAttribute` which doesn't do any computation. It returns the attribute's "real" value.
`src` is the absolute address to the resource